# Blog Social Network Connect Integration with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, social-networking

Using a wordpress plugin called Wordpress Social Login I have allowed users to comment by logging in with various social networks.

The problem is after the authentication takes place in a new window and that window closes, the original window then refreshes. I would like this window not to refresh and instead triggers some javascript to re load certain sections of it.

I have found the line in authentication.php where it closes the window, but cannot find what makes it refresh the current page.

After a lot of PHP is done, this takes place...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function init() {
    window.opener.wsl_wordpress_social_login({
        'action'   : 'wordpress_social_login',
        'provider' : '<?php echo $provider ?>'
    });

    window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">
</body>
</html>
```

That closes the pop up. What makes the main window then refresh and how can I stop it.

Comment: The main window probably has some function that check (like every second) if that other window is still opened. That's how it can detect that popup was closed, then it refreshes the main window. I have never used that plugin, never used Wordpress, but that's how I've seen other similar widgets work.

Comment: Yes, some JavaScript function in the main window will have a function that is envoked from setInterval() to periodically check if that popup window is still opened and if it's not opened then do something like window.location.reload(true)

Comment: No evidence of a setInterval, setTimeout, there are a load of window.location.href in input fields that don't effect it. In authenticate there is this line. I removed it but doing that doesn't trigger the response from the social network <script> 
 setTimeout( function(){window.location.href = window.location.href + "&redirect_to_provider=ture"}, 750 );
</script>

Comment: I think it must be triggered by the pop up because If i close it before it has run it's script it won't refresh the main page

Comment: Find this function in a js file that is included in your main window: wsl_wordpress_social_login I think it may be in this function.

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine  It is this line in that function that rather than reloads the page, submits the form for login. This needs to be done by AJAX.. jQuery('body').append("<form id='loginform' method='post' action='" + login_uri + "'></form>");
   jQuery('#loginform').append("<input type='hidden' id='redirect_to' name='redirect_to' value='" + window.location.href + "'>"); ... How

Comment: I know. We could change the target of the form to an iframe that is set to display none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the parent window does not check if the child window is closed but the popup has something like:

`<body onunload="opener.location=(opener.location)">`

or

`window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;`

somewhere in a script.

Comment: That is it. The child window closes the parent window and fires it to another location in exactly this manner.

Answer (score 0):

the popup seems to call `wsl_wordpress_social_login` before closing.

try to find this function on the plugin code